# Set background-color of <div> as the hex-text text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several divs as follows in my HTML code:

```
<div>#558C89</div>
```

and I want the background of the every div to have the value it holds.
I came up with a script that does that, but only when div is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', $(this).text());
    });
});
```

I'm total beginner in JavaScript and jQuery and I'm not sure if it is even the correct approach. I want those divs to have background colors set already when the page is loaded.

Comment: did you try .text()?

Comment: If you wanted to do this with native javascript, you could do it [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/knt0v26n/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.each()` to iterate through each `<div>` and use `.text()` to extract the hex color code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div').each(function () {
     $(this).css('background-color', $(this).text());
   })
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aj5s1hp0/)

Comment: Yes, I was using .text() but somehow I deleted it from the post, anyway .each() is what I was looking for, it works now. Thank you very much.